# Help Close Duplicate Questions of "Find Out Who Deleted a Remote Git Branch"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I found some duplicate questions that all ask how to find out who deleted a remote Git branch:

- <del>[How to find out who delete a branch at git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010392/how-to-find-out-who-delete-a-branch-at-git)</del> (closed)
- <del>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542930/someone-deleted-git-remote-branch</del> (closed)

I've picked this one as a canonical,

- [Find who deleted a git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179283/find-who-deleted-a-git-branch)

because it's the oldest and has some good answers, though [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010626/456814) is probably the best, so we should have his answer merged into the other question, or vice versa.

I've already used up (and retracted) my close votes because I didn't know about all the duplicates available yet, so I'll need everyone else's help to get these all closed.

Comment: I've seen a couple of these close-voting bloc questions recently.  Why doesn't the normal close voting process suffice?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom it's agonizingly difficult to pull off closing a bunch of questions sometimes, especially older ones, not to mention that it's ***very slow***. Sometimes it can be days before a question is finally closed, if it ends up closed at all. I suppose asking this question on Meta was a little unnecessary for just two questions, but in general, if you want to close questions fast and you don't have a gold-badge close vote, seeking help on Meta just helps get things done much quicker.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom plus, this gives people the opportunity to point out more duplicates, or argue if some questions shouldn't be closed. Another advantage is that I don't have to keep asking people in chat to help close the questions.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom one more thing, [tag:git] happens to not get as much traffic as more popular tags, which makes it ***even more difficult*** to get Git questions closed.